# Write empty strings to MongoDB Output - Pentaho

Tags: mongodb, pentaho, kettle

when I try to write some values into my mongodb output in Pentaho, I would like null values of string fields to be translated to empty strings. Instead the key itself is not appearing in the mongo database. For example, if my field 'name' has a null value or a missing value, then I would like `'name':''` to appear in my mongo collection. Can anyone help me with this issue ?

Comment: You should design a schema for your documents, before store a document, you can check which fields are missing, and set them to '', and `document validation` in MongoDB-3.2 can also help you, detail see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document-validation/

Comment: You can also take a look at `mongoose`, http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html, it can help you to set missing fields to a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `If field value is null` step to convert null values to empty strings. To actually store the empty string in mongo set `KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL` in `kettle.properties`

```
KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL=Y
```

Another solution is to create a schema in mongo, to have default values, like @zydcom says in the comments.

Comment: I have tried that, but the emty strings are still not written into mongo. ... The reason for that is mentioned in these links : http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?79620-How-can-I-replace-null-with-empty-string ... http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-2277 ... null values and empty strings are treated the same way by PDI

Comment: Did you check `Set empty string?` option?

Comment: :) actually tested now, and got it working with `KETTLE_EMPTY_STRING_DIFFERS_FROM_NULL`

Comment: Could you tell me the location of `kettle.properties` ?

Comment: It's located in your home directory in `.kettle/kettle.properties`. This will depend on your operating system.